# how to get term id from current post type instead of name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, terms

following code is returning `name` of all terms associated with my custom Post Type which are under `generetax taxonomy only

```
$terms = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'generetax'); 
echo $terms;
```

Can you please let me know how to get the `term_id` instead of name? I tried this way

```
 echo $terms->term_id;
```

but it is not returning any thing

**

> Update

**

Ok On rnnung this method

```
   $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'generetax'); 
            foeach($terms as $term){
                print_r($term);
            }
```

> WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 3 [name] => Semi [slug] => semi
>   [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 3 [taxonomy] =>
>   generetax[description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw )

but still `$terms->term_id;` return nothing on

```
   $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'generetax'); 
            foeach($terms as $term){
              echo  $terms->term_id;
            }
```

Comment: try `foreach($terms as $term){print_r($term);}` that should tell you what's going on. You can't echo an array, use `print_r`, `var_dump`, or `var_export` instead, then you'll know if it's an object or an array & what it contains..

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: My bad. `get_the_term_list ` returns string. `get_the_terms` will return an array of terms for a given taxo/post_id. `get_terms` will return all terms for a given-taxo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)
will help you. Function return array with terms objects and you can foreach array and retrieve term id for each term attached to post.

Answer (score 0):

If only getting ids of each term in array, no need to foreach each term item, just use php array_column native function :

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'taxonomy');
$terms_ids = array_column($terms, 'term_id');
//output
[array_of_ids]
```

Kiss